# How to use Windows's RemoteDesktopConnection even after restarting the system?

Tags: windows, remote-desktop, remote, remote-access, remote-control

I want to connect a PC to laptop (with Ethernet LAN) and and use Remote Desktop Connection to control it . My PC is going to NOT have mouse , keyboard and monitor in a week . When I use Remote Desktop Connection , I have to log into system to let my laptop control it , but after I restart the system I cant login . (Because I dont have mouse and keyboard) what should I do so that I can just power up the PC and remote control it with my laptop ? Is it possible ? THanks :)

+EDIT :
When I try to connect to remote access I get these errors :
1 - Remote access to the server is not renabled
2 - the remote computer is turned off 
3 - the remote computer is not available on the network

I need tolog in and refresh the networks list to be able to remote control it .

+EDIT2 :
PC and laptop are connected over direct (single) LAN cable . I tried with both IP and hostname , but I get the same error . I wait enough after reboot , nothing happens , but after  a few minutes trying to connect to host my network status changes to "No network" (that red X) from "waiting" (that blue circle) and I still get the same error ;

Comment: You should be able to log into RDP after a restart (once Windows is loaded), and the target machine not having a mouse/KB or monitor shouldn't matter.  Is the target machine booting back into Windows after you restart it?

Comment: Yes ! It has windows 8 and boots into windows in login window ! (waiting for me to enter password) , in this situation I cant remote access it , I should log in , go to networks , refresh the list and then I can remote access it . (I will write the error in a couple minutes)

Comment: Which version of Windows 8, and are you using a wired or wireless network connecting on that target machine?

Comment: I am using Windows 8.1 64 bit on PC and on laptop it is Windows 7 64 bit . They are connected with Ethernet LAN to each other . (NO wireless) and these are the errors :

Comment: 1 - Remote access to the server is not renabled
2 - the remote computer is turned off 
3 - the remote computer is not available on the network

Comment: You have to figure out why your networking isn't working before you log in; it should be, so there's something wrong with or misconfigured on that target machine. Start by checking the Event Logs.

Comment: I'm confused about your statement "refresh the list", what list exactly? Usually you only get a list of network if you're using WiFi...

Comment: Well ! Thanks :) so there is something wrong with my host network and not RemoteDesktopConnection , right ? O.o

Comment: You can configure windows to automatically logged into a user account have you done that?

Comment: Wow ! ThankU @Ramhound ! I just found this ! I'm gonna try that :)

Comment: You say they're connected over Ethernet but nothing is said of the intervening infrastructure - is it a direct connection, with a single cable connecting the two computers, or are there any switches/routers in between? Is the server set up to use DHCP or a static IP? If DHCP, do you have an IP reservation configured for the server? Are you trying to RDP using hostname or IP address - does one work, but not the other? How long are you waiting after the reboot to log in?

Comment: To remove some networking issues from the equation, set the server to a static IP and try connecting to it by IP address instead of hostname. If that doesn't work, do some basic network troubleshooting. Try pinging the IP. If ping responds but RDP still doesn't work, do a TCP connection test to port 3389 to make sure the service is listening for your connection. (You can use any number of third-party utilities for this, or [PowerShell](http://stuart.weenig.com/2013/08/checking-if-tcp-port-is-open-on-remote.html).

Comment: Keep in mind that all services on a system aren't going to be fully available the second you press the on switch. Even after it's booted to the login screen, there may still be background applications and utilities that have not yet completed launching. So, don't be surprised if RDP isn't available just a few seconds after the login screen shows up. If you've waited several minutes since the login screen was available, and port 3389 still isn't responding but the system is otherwise reachable (pingable), then there's probably an issue with the RDP service startup or other network services.

Comment: @Iszi I added those additional information to the question ; that pinging and TCP solution seems like the best troubleshooting way . I'll try that tonight and reply the results here . Thanks :)

Comment: @ArdeshirIzadi Any particular reason you don't have a router/switch between the systems? That'll probably help a lot.

Comment: @Iszi I just found out pinging doesn't work and found the reason that I changed some IPV4 network settings before in my DesktopPC . ThankU ! You just solved my 3day problem today :) U deserve the best . And yeah I'm gonna use the router , I just wanted to make sure if the problems are not by the router . Thanks :)